# Change gradient annotation size in graphic style instance without breaking graphic style link in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to be able to extend the size of a gradient which has a fill that is an instance of a shared graphic style. I want to be able to extend/shorten the length of this gradient without breaking the link to the shared graphic style. I understand that you can't change the direction/color of the gradient without breaking the shared graphic style link, but it seems like you should be able to change the size since the size of the gradient is dependent on the instance of the shape it's applied to anyways.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Gradient Annotator** and create a **Style** with this new gradient

[image: Gradient annotator]

[image: style]

Comment: Great, although the point is kind of to not create a new style—as I'd have, well, dozens or hundreds of styles after applying all the variations in annotation sizes that I want for my design.

Comment: @nikkwong then using styles may not be best. Create one "master" style, apply it then adjust the gradient for each object. If objects aren't visually the same, graphic styles aren't good for anything other than creating a "starting point" for further alterations.